# how to fix toggle first click after reload page

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle

I have [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oneng/747cy/3/)

```
<h2>TITLE INFO</h2>

<div>text 1</div>
<div>text 2</div>
<div>text 3</div>




jQuery('h2').toggle(function () {
    jQuery('body').addClass('order_list');
    $.cookie('info_type', 'order_list', {
        expires: 30
    });
}, function () {
    jQuery('body').removeClass('order_list');
    $.cookie('info_type', null);
});

var order_list_var = $.cookie('info_type');
jQuery('body').addClass(order_list_var);
```

If cookie set and i reload page, then try click to h2: nothing happens
Only if i click second time, cookie and class be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `toggle`, you could use `click`. Like this:

```
jQuery('h2').click(function(){
    if (jQuery('body').hasClass('order_list')){
        jQuery('body').removeClass('order_list');
        $.cookie('info_type', null);
    }
    else{
        jQuery('body').addClass('order_list');
        $.cookie('info_type', 'order_list', {
            expires: 30
        });
    }
});
```

The problem you have is: when you reload the page and click the `h2`, it always executes the first function of the `toggle` regardless of the current state of the `h2`. Using the `click` like this, you have complete control over the state of the `h2`